# (Swift 2) How can i get a random Realm object within my Database?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I just wondered if there is a way to get a random realm entry from my Realm Database in swift 2
Reason for this is being that I want to get a random realm object within a certain category.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use random index to retrieve an object. Like the following.

```
let dogs = realm.objects(Dog)
let randomDog = dogs[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(dogs.count) - 1))]
```

Comment: This will crash if you have 0 dogs and also it will always miss the last dog in your database as it does not require the -1 within arc4random_uniform